# Leafet map & VB.net

Tags: json, vb.net, leaflet, cefsharp

I am having extended issues trying to plot a route from waypoints on a map loaded from an xml file containing pos lats and longs. The leaflet map loads as expected and plots the waypoints with markers but does not seem to like connecting them with a poly line. Any ideas?

When running the code i get this error line in the debug output: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading '0')", source: https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js (5)

I have tried numerous different methods of reordering the events and how the functions are called, all to no success.

HTML CODE:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Stamen Terrain Map</title>
    <!-- Leaflet CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" />
    <!-- Leaflet JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map" style="height: 500px;"></div>
    <button id="showRouteButton">Show Route</button>

<script>
    var map = L.map('map').setView([0, 0], 2); // Centered on the world map, zoom level 2

    L.tileLayer('https://stamen-tiles-{s}.a.ssl.fastly.net/terrain/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg', {
        maxZoom: 14,
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://stamen.com/" target="_blank">Stamen Design</a> &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright" target="_blank">OpenStreetMap contributors</a>'
    }).addTo(map);

    // Creating an empty feature group to store the route lines
    var routeLines = L.featureGroup().addTo(map);

    // Function to plot a waypoint on the map
    function plotWaypoint(lat, lng) {
        L.marker([lat, lng]).addTo(map);
    }

    // Function to display the route
    function showRoute(routeCoordinates) {
        if (routeCoordinates.length > 1) {
            // Clear any previous route lines
            routeLines.clearLayers();

            for (var i = 0; i < routeCoordinates.length - 1; i++) {
                var startPoint = routeCoordinates[i];
                var endPoint = routeCoordinates[i + 1];

                // Check if startPoint and endPoint are defined
                if (startPoint && endPoint) {
                    var route = [startPoint, endPoint];
                    L.polyline(route, { color: 'blue' }).addTo(routeLines);
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>



</body>
</html>
```

VB.NET CODE:

```html
Dim webView As ChromiumWebBrowser


    Private Sub LoadMap()
        ' Load your HTML file
        Dim htmlFilePath As String = Application.StartupPath & "\WMap.html"
        MsgBox(htmlFilePath)
        ChromiumWebBrowser1.Load(htmlFilePath)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Guna2Button6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Guna2Button6.Click
        LoadMap()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Guna2Button7_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Guna2Button7.Click
        plotwaypointsfromxml()
    End Sub

    Private Sub plotwaypointsfromxml()
        ' Load the XML file
        Dim xmlFile As String = Application.StartupPath & "\Test.xml"
        Dim xmlDoc As New XmlDocument()
        xmlDoc.Load(xmlFile)

        ' Find the navlog element
        Dim navlogNode As XmlNode = xmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/OFP/navlog")

        If navlogNode IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim routeCoordinates As New List(Of Object)

            ' Loop through each fix element
            For Each fixNode As XmlNode In navlogNode.SelectNodes("fix")
                Dim lat As Double
                Dim lng As Double

                ' Extract latitude and longitude from fix element
                Double.TryParse(fixNode.SelectSingleNode("pos_lat").InnerText, lat)
                Double.TryParse(fixNode.SelectSingleNode("pos_long").InnerText, lng)

                ' Add the waypoint to the routeCoordinates array
                routeCoordinates.Add(New Object() {lat, lng})
            Next

            ' Plot waypoints first
            For Each coord As Object In routeCoordinates
                Dim lat As Double = CDbl(coord(0))
                Dim lng As Double = CDbl(coord(1))
                ChromiumWebBrowser1.ExecuteScriptAsync("plotWaypoint", New Object() {lat, lng})
            Next

            ' Call the JavaScript showRoute function in the WebBrowser control

            ChromiumWebBrowser1.ExecuteScriptAsync("showRoute", New Object() {routeCoordinates})
        End If

    End Sub
```